# QGIS problem with UTM grid coordinates in map composer

Tags: qgis, utm

I'm trying to create a map just using an OSM open layer as a base with no other vector/raster data. When I go to map composer and add a grid to my map, I selected the UTM zone 51N (as it's in the Philippines) and used map units as the grid unit. But, when the coordinates show up, they don't seem to correspond to the map. Am I missing a step somewhere? [image: map of Barugo with coordinates][image]

Comment: Can you provide another screen shot showing the part when you set the grid to your map in composer? I'm interested in seeing the choices for the labeling.

Comment: I attached a screenshot, is that what you mean?

Comment: Well, i think that you should try to use the same CRS as the default layer!

Comment: can you say what values you expect to see, those look ok to me, but I don't know where your map is :-)

Comment: Is your area near Barugo? If so according to Google earth they seem to be ok, what exactly is the problem

Comment: @iant, you're right, I just was misreading the grid. The coordinates are correct for my map!